# Преобразовать коллекцию в объект с ключами, равными id

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли в Laravel метод наподобие `toArray()`, в результате работы которого получается массив с ключами, равными `id` элементов? Метод `toArray()` не устанавливает ключи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть метод [`keyBy`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keyby).

```
$roles = Role::all()->keyBy('id');
```

---

Если вы не используете Eloquent, коллекцию можно создать вручную:

```
$roles = collect(DB::table('roles')->get())->keyBy('id');
```

---

В Laravel 5.3+ конструктор запросов возвращает коллекцию, поэтому оборачивать результат выборки в коллекцию нет необходимости:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->get()->keyBy('id');
```

---

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131362/2486051) на вопрос "[Eloquent column list by key with array as values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130507/eloquent-column-list-by-key-with-array-as-values)"